# insert row per week in date period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very big table of the kind: `user_id, started_at, ends_at, group_id`

I need to do some analytics on this so I'm trying to pre-calculate some values, in this specific case I'm looking to create a table like:
active_in_week with `id, user_id, active_week` where active_week is every week between `started_at` and `ends_at`

So for a row with `started_at` 2017-01-01 and `ends_at` 2017-01-31 the result would be 4 rows:

```
id user_id, active_week
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 3
4, 1, 4
```

I would prefer to do this at the query level instead of on a programming language due to the size/speed of this table. The purpose is to do additional queries after that will be aggregating values per week.

Right now if I do those queries in a normalized state they run for up to 8hrs with proper indexes.

Comment: You're going to need something along the lines of a calendar table here.  SQL was designed to extract data, not create it.  And handling this from your application sounds OK to me.

Comment: Clearly you've thought about it. Nevertheless, are you sure that your intended approach is the most sensible?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure its the most sensible, the data is highly normalized which is causing some poor performance in complicated queries, so I'm trying to denormalize a few parts that reduce the amount of rows looked at and at same time makes easier to write queries.

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise (not much is), but I just find it a little implausible that this stategy will provide any performance benefit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Given the amount of time it takes to run outside of the database I don't think its feasible. Thank you for the calendar table suggestion, I think I see what you mean something like: join over the calendar table `where calendar.week between week(started_at) and week(ends_at)`?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, from my "calculations" it will reduce the rows looked at by a lot. Since this table has billions of rows and I'll be reducing this to at most count(users) * number of weeks in a year which is a few hundreds of thousand. If it was just a one off query I could deal with 8hrs but this will be needed for multiple different queries.

Comment: So you've already looked at partitioning?

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe can work with the away like this (attn: it is getting a bit tricky):

```
CREATE TABLE weeks AS (
   SELECT weekId, MIN(date) as starts_at, MAX(date) as ends_at
   FROM (
      SELECT 
        YEARWEEK(started_at) AS weekId,
        started_at AS date,
      FROM srctable
      UNION
      SELECT 
        YEARWEEK(ends_at) AS weekId,
        ends_at AS date,
      FROM srctable

   )
   GROUP BY weekId          
)
```

Then you should have a table that knows all weeks, start- and end-dates of your data.

The you can do a join on the weeks table.